# How do you select elements based on their style?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Using jQuery, how would you find elements which have a particular style (eg: `float: left`), regardless of whether it's an inline style or one defined in a CSS file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using the [filter function](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter):

```
$('*').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('float') == 'left';
});
```

Replace '*' with the appropriate selectors for your case.

Comment: Much better solution than mine I think.

Comment: Yeah, +1 good answer, but for sanitys and speeds sake one may want to reduce the search field to something less than '*'

Comment: You should use `this.css.float` instead of creating a new jQuery object for every iteration of the filter.

Comment: @Alnitak You need to make it an object if you want to use jQuery's `.css()`. Reason being that `.css()` isn't a javascript function, so you will still need to use `$(this)`. You can use `$(this).css.float` but it won't find `left` because `float` isn't an index. If you want to use strict `this` you have to select it differently with something like `this.attributes.style.nodeValue.search(/float:(\s)?left/i) != -1` accounting for the fact that other properties can set 'left'. So even with the overhead, `$(this).css('float')` is the best bet IMO.

Answer (score 11):

This is gonna be slow.  Like REALLY slow.  If you know you need to select all elements with a given CSS style, you will see much better performance by applying a single additional css rule to each element, and then selecting by that rule.

It's going to be MUCH faster and more readable to boot.

CSS:

```
.float-left {float:left}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.float-left');
```

Comment: I just came back and read this question again, and am now slightly embarrassed by it. This would definitely have been the best solution. I can't imagine why I needed to select elements like this...

Answer (score -2):

Well, I don't know if I would approach this this way. Why not just rename those elements with a consistent ID or class name, and select that?

If that's not an option, this should work:

```
this.getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).style.float = 'left';
```

I think.

Comment: This will not work. Your code selects all divs, reduces selection to the first div, then sets its float to left.