# Find div with style attribute jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to select all html inside div that has style attribute on it..
here is fiddle url [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/GctRf/)

```
 var testst = $('div').css('margin');
 alert(testst.html());
```

i am not able to get result.

Comment: Can you not put a `class` or `id` attribute on that div? It's what they're for. Selecting by a CSS attribute is highly un-semantic.

Comment: is it ok ? : http://jsfiddle.net/GctRf/2/

Comment: similar topic already discussed 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442048/how-do-you-select-elements-based-on-their-style

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an attribute selector:

```
$('div[style]')
```

However, using this to find an element with a *specific* style (CSS rule) is a **bad idea**. It will only work for inline styles actually set using `style="whatever"` and your attribute value in the selector (`div[style="whatever"]`) would have to match the attribute *exactly*.

So... the proper way to do it is to add a `class` attribute to the relevant elements and select them using this class (`div.whatever` for `class="whatever"` or `class="foo whatever bar"`).

If you still need to find elements with a certain CSS rule the most reliable way would be to iterate over all of them and check if they have the given style:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('whatever') == 'the_value';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.i know its bad idea to use inline style but i am fetching html from another site :) So no i didn't write the html