# Javascript/JQuery: How do I select the link inside a <td> element when it has a certain style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a website with multiple td elements. I need to a way to click on all the href links inside the td element if it matches a certain style.

Here is what the td element typically looks like

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"><a class="theclass" href="https://youtube.com" target="_blank">Link</a></td>
```

Can someone please help guide me on how to do this properly? I tried an if statement to see if the td style matches `"font-size: 12px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"`, but it didn't work at all.

Edit: This isn't my website. Sorry, I didn't include this.

Comment: Why not give it a unique class for each design?

Comment: @linus  Because this isn't my website. This is just so things will be easier for me.

Comment: How to select items based on style, check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442048/how-do-you-select-elements-based-on-their-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are going to have to do a Javascript loop.

```
 function clickCertainStyles() {
   $('td').each(function(i, td) {
     var $td = $(td);
     if ($td.css('font-size') == '12px' && $td.css('text-align') == 'center')
       $td.find('a').trigger('click')
   })
 }
```

You can make it faster if you pass in a table container, so you aren't searching the whole page for every TD reference.

Comment: Well, that works, but you don't have to do it...probably.  Some CSS style values can be used as selectors.

Comment: Depending on how many links are on the page it might be faster to use `$("a").closest("td").each()`, especially if the links have some distinguishing class that can be added to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

This will select the `td` element above:

```
$('td[style*="font-weight:bold"]')
```

You'll have to experiment with what works and what doesn't.  I tried things like `width: 100px` and it wouldn't work; presumably anything with a pixel value in it is in some way ambiguous.  However, if I used just `width` it worked for any element that had a width specified.

Note that this only works with inline styles.