# Find image tag inside p with specific class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple `<p>` element on my page. The data in this `<p>` element is coming from the database.

here is my code.
First type of `<p>` Element

```
<p><img class="img img-responsive" src="image_url" alt="" width="235" height="41"></p>
```

Second type of `<p>` Element with `style` attribute (this style also coming from database)

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
       <img class="img img-responsive" src="image_url" alt="" width="235" height="41">
</p>
```

Now i want to add `class` `center-block`to image, whose `<p>` tag have style attribute like this.

`<p style="text-align: center;>`

I am doing this with following jquery code.

```
<script>
    $( "p" ).find( "img" ).addClass('center-block');
</script>
```

**Problem**

But the problem is that class `center-block` is applied to both images. I want to apply this to only image which is in second type of `<p>` element.  **How can i do this?**

Comment: use `each`, and check the style.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading, since you're trying to find a `p` with a specific attribute that is not at all a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you select elements based on their style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442048/how-do-you-select-elements-based-on-their-style)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve only paragraphs with that style in the attributes (starting with `text-align`)

```
$( "p[style^='text-align'] img" ).addClass('center-block');
```

---

in *VanillaJS* :

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("p[style^='text-align'] img"), function(el) {
    el.classList.add('center-block');
})
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGKrQd)

Comment: Thanks for showing vanilla JS too. Did you know that `querySelectorAll` supports `forEach` natively. So you can do this: `document.querySelectorAll("p[style^='text-align'] img").forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.add('center-block');
})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute css selector:

```
 $('p[style="text-align: center"] img').addClass('center-block');
```

this will work only if whole style is like that include space, if you have other styles you can use this selector

```
'p[style*="text-align: center"] img'
```

and if you don't know if you have space you can use two attribute selectors:

```
'p[style*="text-align: center"] img, p[style*="text-align:center"] img'
```

you can also write custom pseudo selector (in JavaScript) like `:style(text-align: center)` that's more complex and I think it's not needed for your case.

And side note as you can see in my code there are no find since you don't need it you can have single selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").each(function(){
  if($(this).css('text-align') == "center") {
    $(this).find('img').addClass('center-block');
  }
});
```

This will check every p element and for ones where the styling contains text-align: center it'll set its child image(s) to include the center-block class

Comment: this will select the p if text-align is set in style sheet, not sure if this matter though.

Comment: I think .css can be used to get any computed style, whether its origin be from a style sheet or inline

Comment: Yes but you can't distinguish the two, they work the same. So you can select p that don't have style attribute at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the filter function

```
$( "li" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return $( this ).attr( "style" ) === "text-align: center";
  })
    .addClass('center-block');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select checking the css property `text-align` to match the one you gave, here a working snippet:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "p[style='text-align: center;']" ).find( "img" ).addClass('center-block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><img class="img img-responsive" src="https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="41"></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">

<img class="img img-responsive" src="https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="41">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its enough to find all `p` with style attribute

```
<script>
    $( "p[style] img" ).addClass('center-block');
</script>
```